# Is there any solution to deal "Save as pdf" pop up for window print function in Selenium Web driver?

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to save the Webpage content as pdf, so when I'm trying to use the below code

```
((JavascriptExecutor)DriverHolder.getDriver()).executeScript("window.print=function(){};");  
   DriverHolder.getDriver().findElement(By.xpath("//button[@onclick=\"window.print()\"]")).click();
```

"Save As pdf" pop up is appearing, is there any way to save the pdf?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

just get that save button element and click it will get saved
see how

In my case it is

```
//*[@id="sidebar"]//print-preview-button-strip//div/cr-button[2]/text()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vG1Np.png)

Comment: when we are interacting with this pop up, we have to deal with windows pop up,im expecting without dealing with those pop up  is there any way to save the pdf

Comment: what is the issue with pop-up?

Comment: Im not able to interact with the pop up using selenium

Comment: @WBPHELPFebKaya see example here https://www.browserstack.com/guide/alerts-and-popups-in-selenium